# Is there a way to place bars between ticks in d3js?

Tags: d3.js

Does somebody has an idea how it is possible to create a bar chart in d3js, where the bars begin at the position of a tick on the x axis and end on the next one, so that the bar is exactly between the ticks? The actual value is on the y axis.